# Tool to generate build.xml files for ant

Tags: java, ant

I am working on some Java projects and using `ant` to build my projects. The environment and the project structure is such that I cannot use any IDE.

Hence, I am looking for a good tool that can generate `build.xml` files to be used with ant (if possible something similar to `autotools` for c++).

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185921/any-way-to-generate-ant-build-xml-file-automatically-from-eclipse

Comment: If you want automatisation, **maven** would be a replacement of **ant**, worth investigating. Especially as it builds on "best practices" and conventions. It also does dependency management (like **ivy** for use with ant).

Comment: If your build is such that an automated tool can generate your build.xml, then I agree with Joop, Maven is a better choice. It uses convention over explicit configuration, and makes dependency management a breeze.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No such thing as a "standard" ANT file. This makes it difficult to develop a generic ANT file generator.
Course there's nothing stopping you from writing one yourself (simplified example below)

Don't forget that ANT is very cross-platform, unlike **make**. This might explain the lack of tools equivalent to autotools.

## Simple ANT file generator

This example uses a simple template file called **build.xml.template**:

```
<project name="%PROJECT_NAME%" default="helloworld">

    <target name="helloworld" description="Pretty pointless ANT target">
        <echo message="%MESSAGE%"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

The UNIX sed command can then be used to substitute values and generate the ANT file:

```
$ sed -e 's/%PROJECT_NAME%/hello world/' -e 's/%MESSAGE%/hello world/' build.xml.template
```

This is a really simple generator. I'd suggest investigate a proper template engine for a more powerful solution.

## Alternatives

### Maven

As suggested in other answers, Maven can be used to [generate new projects](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html):

```
$ mvn archetype:generate
```

Still end up with a rather complex XML based file that might need further tweaking.

### Gradle

If you're looking for a Java build tool with a simple build specification, nothing beats [Gradle](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#tutorial_java_projects).

**build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```

All you need is to compile a Java project with no external dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I work a lot in ANT but I always write build.xml manually in edit plus.