# Eclipse - create an ant task for running a class

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, junit

In Eclipse, it is very easy to run Java classes and Junit tests with a click, Eclipse does all the hard work of figuring out the class path.

But if I want to create an Ant task that will run a specific Java class or Junit test - I have to figure it out myself.

Is there a way to tell Eclipse to automatically create an ant build file for these tasks?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any way to generate ant build.xml file automatically from Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185921/any-way-to-generate-ant-build-xml-file-automatically-from-eclipse)

Comment: This deals with ant files for *building* a jar. I asked for an ant  task that will *run* a specific Java class or Junit test.

Comment: you mean [java](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) and [junit](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html) task?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a way to create them automatically from Eclipse, with all the required classpath elements etc.