# Is Viewing JUnit results in TeamCity possible?

Tags: java, junit, teamcity

I'm in the process of setting up a project which uses TeamCity to build the project and run the unit tests.

The first has been done successfully and the project builds. However I can't figure out how to set up TeamCity *or* my build.xml such that I can view the success or failure of each individual test. Although I'm quite sure I'm attacking this from the wrong angle.

Below is my build.xml:

```
<project>
<property name="test" location="tests"/>
<target name="test">
  <junit printsummary="yes" fork="yes" haltonfailure="yes">
    <formatter type="plain"/>
      <batchtest fork="true">
        <fileset dir="${test}">
          <include name="**/*Test*.java"/>
        </fileset>
      </batchtest>
    </junit>
  </target>
</project>
```

Comment: Ok, this is much bigger than I thought. I'll be back shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185921/any-way-to-generate-ant-build-xml-file-automatically-from-eclipse) on stack overflow answered my main problem. So I'll close this.

Simply generating the ANT build file from within eclipse did the trick.

Now for the reporting...